# How to flatten a JSON using Awk?

Tags: json, bash, awk

I want to flatten a JSON string the way `jq` does it, but don't have `jq` disponible where my script will run.

I have an input like this:

```
[
    {
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "foo": "bar"
        }
    }
]
```

And want something like this as output:

```
State.Status: "running"
State.foo: "bar"
```

I think it can be done using `awk`, but don't know from where to start.

Comment: Can't you just copy `jq` to the target system? It's a single binary, very simple.

Comment: It can't be done robustly with awk. Even the GNU awk JSON extension has limits but you could maybe give that a shot. Having said that, post your worst-case, most complicated sample input/output and as long as the rest of what you have to handle is guaranteed to always follow that format then maybe we can help with a restricted hack.

Comment: Do you have perl or python available if not jq?

Comment: I ended up using the json module of python.

Comment: @EdMorton the  awk language is not turing-complete?

Comment: @EdMorton I'm only saying that if `awk` is turing-complete (wich `sed` isn't, I think) it can be done robustly with it, not saying it would be easy, though. Theoretically, it can be done even with the `brainfuck` language :P

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought you were saying and what I'm saying is good luck with that. Theory and practice are only identical in theory, in practice they're very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a script that'll do what you want with the input you posted but YMMV with any other input:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/"[^"]+"/) {
    tag = substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
    $0  = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
$1 == "}"  { name = ""; next }
$NF == "{" { name = tag; next }
$1 !~ /[][]/ {
    match($0,/"[^"]+"/)
    val = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    print name "." tag ": " val
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
State.Status: "running"
State.foo: "bar"
```

Comment: It might be worth pointing out to the OP some of the limits of this approach (f/e, parsing `{"Status": "waiting: \"30-second timeout\""}` won't go so well, while a fully compliant JSON parser would have no problem with it).

Comment: I feel like the OPs had enough of a warning with [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419848/how-to-flatten-a-json-using-awk/58422274?noredirect=1#comment103186260_58419848) and saying in the answer that YMMV with any other input. There's just so many cases it won't work for it's not worth listing some of them.